# Unable to get JSON when i am working with unirest in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unirest

I tried multiple times but I am not able to get why I am not able to get the JSON data. I installed the Unirest via Composer but still i am not getting JSON.
Below is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Unirest\Request as UnirestRequest;

class DomainController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
    $headers = array('Accept' => 'application/json');
    $data = array('name' => 'ahmad', 'company' => 'mashape');
    $response = UnirestRequest::post('http://mockbin.com/request', $headers, $data);
    return $response->body;
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any error or any output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the last line to `return response()->json($response->body);`

Comment: May i ask you one thing. Why we use ````response()````